# Android FaceDetector.findFaces doesn't find any faces

Tags: android, face-detection

This is a code I have written to run android's face detector. Unfortunately, it doesn't find any. I have put this in a onPreviewFrame(data, camera).

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
Camera.Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();
YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width, size.height, null);
Rect rectangle = new Rect(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int quality = 100;
image.compressToJpeg(rectangle, quality, stream);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(stream.toByteArray(), 0, stream.size());
FaceDetector detector = new FaceDetector(size.width, size.height, 5);
FaceDetector.Face[] faces = new FaceDetector.Face[5];
int numFaces = detector.findFaces(bitmap, faces);
textView.setText("numFaces = " + numFaces);
```

Any ideas? fixes?

Comment: Have you ever dumped your bitmap and checked whether it is correct?

Comment: yes, I have done that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check whether your bitmap data is correct firstly. You must `setPreviewSize` before `startPreview`. check whether the size is same as your preview data. or you can hard code it to (640, 480) for a test. If your bitmap is correct. maybe the API cannot work due to the input data quality. you can dump some data, and try other app or lib, such as OpenCV, to verify. Good luck.

Comment: I'm sure that quality is good enough. I'm sending the images to a server and they look good.

Comment: If so, I suppose the conclusion is the detection API cannot work on your device. Have you verified the code on other devices?